# Optimizing FirstOrDefault

Tags: c#, optimization, .net, ienumerable

I'm working on an application in which it takes quite a bit of time to initialize the data.

Some background: I'm creating a sort of pivot table in which I turn Figure 1 below into Figure 2. I've gone through with `Stopwatch`s and have been able to isolate a single line of code that takes 2 seconds during program load (it is in a loop called for roughly 2-300 rows of data, 2 seconds is the total time across all iterations). That line is marked in the code example below, Figure 3.

**My question** is if there is a better way to structure the example method such that I can avoid whatever overhead that line is causing. It is worth noting that when that line executes, `mChar` contains sometimes 0 elements, <strike>but up to around 5</strike> or 1 (see edit below), so I can't imagine what would cause this to take so much time to execute.

#### Figure 1

```
SAMPLENUMBER | ANALYSIS_NAME | ANALYSIS_STATUS
----------------------------------------------
   1234      |     NO3       |       I
   1234      |     SO4       |       C
   5678      |     NO3       |       C
```

#### Figure 2

```
SAMPLENUMBER |     NO3       |      SO4
----------------------------------------------
   1234      |      I        |       C
   5678      |      C        |
```

#### Figure 3

```cs
private List<string> GetPivotData(DataRow sourceRow, DataTable sourceTable)
{
  int pivotStartIndex = sourceTable.Columns.IndexOf(Cols.HotDate) + 1;
  var retList = new List<string>(sourceTable.Columns.Count - pivotStartIndex);
  for (int i = pivotStartIndex; i < sourceTable.Columns.Count; i++)
  {
    string[] elementTest = sourceTable.Columns[i].ColumnName.Split('-');
    var mChars = 
        from s in mainData.AsEnumerable()
        where s.Field<string>(Cols.Samplenumber) == sourceRow.Field<string>(Cols.Samplenumber)
          && s.Field<string>(Cols.ElementName) == elementTest[0].Trim()
          && s.Field<string>(Cols.AnalysisNumber) == elementTest[1].Trim()
        select s.Field<string>(Cols.AnalysisStatus);
    retList.Add(mChars.FirstOrDefault()); // <-- this is the line taking so much time.
  }
  return retList;
}
```

I've tried things like having `retList` as an array rather than a list, as well as calling `.ToList()` on my LINQ result and using `.Find(x => true)` and they really haven't had any effect. The method in Figure 3 is itself inside a `for` loop, called roughly 200 times, once per sample. The `for` loop inside the method itself iterates on average 5 times, so that line of code gets called about 1000 times, depending on the data. That means that the average time for the line is around 2ms, which may just be too small in itself to be able to do anything with. Swapping my `for` loops for `Parallel.For` halves the time it takes, but I've found that my logic doesn't work well with concurrency. At all.

Edit: I should clarify why I'm using `FirstOrDefault()` I suppose and I need to clarify an error in my initial post as well. The error is that I said `mChars` can contain up to 5 elements when `FirstOrDefault()` is called (it is `retList` that has up to 5). It will only ever have 0 or 1 element(s). When it's empty, I still need to add a `null` to the list, so I'm looking into a way to add the `mChars` result directly to the list without any searches at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line with `from` only defines the enumeration, but it doesn't actually run over the list and apply your `select` clause. In your case, that one is only applied when you call `FirstOrDefault`.

Therefore, to speed up the call to `FirstOrDefault` you need to speed up your `where` condition. I mean this one:

```
s.Field<string>(Cols.Samplenumber) == sourceRow.Field<string>(Cols.Samplenumber)
      && s.Field<string>(Cols.ElementName) == elementTest[0].Trim()
      && s.Field<string>(Cols.AnalysisNumber) == elementTest[1].Trim()
```

The most expensive parts about this are probably the calls to `s.Field<string>(...)`, followed by the `Trim()` calls. All of these can be cached. Just convert the `maindata` into something that's cheap to access, and only do the conversion once, outside of the for loop. Something more or less like this (this won't run as is, only use it as inspiration):

```
struct TempItem
{
    public string Samplenumber;
    public string ElementName;
    public string AnalysisNumber;
    public string AnalysisStatus;
}
string sourceSampleNumber = sourceRow.Field<string>(Cols.Samplenumber);
var lookUpList = mainData.AsEnumerable().Where(i => i.Samplenumber == sourceSampleNumber).Select(i=> new TempItem {
        Samplenumber = s.Field<string>(Cols.Samplenumber),
        ElementName = s.Field<string>(Cols.ElementName),
        AnalysisNumber = s.Field<string>(Cols.AnalysisNumber),
        AnalysisStatus = s.Field<string>(Cols.AnalysisStatus)
    }).ToList(); // the ToList() part here forces application of the linq expressions

for (int i = pivotStartIndex; i < sourceTable.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    string[] elementTest = sourceTable.Columns[i].ColumnName.Split('-');
    string elementName = elementTest[0].Trim();
    string analysisNumber = elementTest[1].Trim();
    var mChars = lookUpList.Where(i => i.ElementName == elementName && i.AnalysisNumber == analysisNumber).Select(i=>i.AnalysisStatus);
    retList.Add(mChars.FirstOrDefault()); 
}
```

Comment: I'm relatively fresh to LINQ, and your answer makes sense in the context of my metrics, as well as the fact that when I break on that line, I have to refresh the Results View to see what `mChars` contains. I was wondering why that query was happening seemingly instantly when I timed it, and the Add was taking so much longer. So basically the query just defines "if anything needs something out of `mChars`, here is how to get the data for it", and none of the actual legwork is done until that `FirstOrDefault` happens?

Comment: Yes, usually that's true. Keep in mind that they are allowed to change the implementation to some extent between framework versions.

Comment: Welp, I used your example code as a guide, and holy heck that's fast! Your solution does make a lot of sense, and it seems I was approaching this from the wrong direction all along. I'll definitely keep this in mind in my future LINQ endeavors. Thanks!

Comment: @helrich LINQ works off `IQueryable<T>`; the query doesn't get *materialized* until its results are being iterated over. `First`, `FirstOrDefault`, `ToList` and a couple other methods *will* materialize the query. This is true for LINQ-to-objects, but this mechanism is especially important to bear in mind when working with LINQ-to-Entities or LINQ-to-SQL, since the database will only get hit when the query gets materialized. I don't think it's likely to ever change in future versions, the LINQ provider is responsible for this.

Comment: The technical term for this is *deferred execution* (*lazy evaluation* is also possible but the former is specifically used in combination with LINQ).